# PATH for the Blender 2.90 executable, in the Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon filesystem, please?

Tags: path, linux

Executable PATH for Blender 2.90 in Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon?

In OpenShot->Preferences->blender path, it requires the PATH to the blender executable.

The GUI Menu (Cinnamon) has the following path to blender 2.90 which works fine with the GUI Launcher:

file:///usr/bin/flatpak%20run%20--branch=stable%20--arch=x86_64%20--command=blender%20--file-forwarding%20org.blender.Blender%20@@%20%25f%20@@

Where is the blender 2.90 executable located in the Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon filesystem, please?

Yes, changing the system PATH to include this directory is needed too, but I can do that once I know what path & filename to use.

Comment: you could download Blender from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/) and unzip it somewhere, then you would definitely know where it is. i think your problem comes from using flatpack. also you could type `which blender` in the terminal, it might give you a location

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Blender 2.90 was installed by the Synaptic Software Manager from the Drop down Menu in Cinnamon. I know not where it was installed. Interesting, "Which" command IS in my system, but does not return anything, not even an error. Trying which -h returns which -a (args) so I know its there. Thanks

Comment: "which" is an utility to find out the location of a binary file. So if you can start Blender by typing "blender" in the terminal, typing "which blender" will tell you the path of blender's executable, and then you can use that in openshot

Comment: Let me rephrase: I can lefdt-click the Mint Menu Icon and the appplications Menu pops up. Under Graphics, Blender is shown and launches correctly. How do I get that same launcher application and directories to OpenShot as if I had Browsed for it? I do not know where Blender launcher is, nor does PATH, so Find, Where, ect does not deliver the path/application. thanks

Comment: the problem is that your blender installation is in a flatpack container which means you get a launcher but no direct access to the executable (they're not the same thing). So like i said, download it from blender.org, write down where you unpacked it and use that path in openshot, problem solved. (sidenote: linuxmint uses flatpack to package a more up to date version of blender, if you'd installed with "sudo apt install blender" then "which blender" would give you a path like "/usr/bin/blender" but it would be an older version, like 2.82)